# save input data in php to notepad.txt

Tags: php

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    <h1>BARCODE GENERATOR</h1>
    <div id="generator"> Please fill in the code :
        <input  type="text" name="barcodeValue" id="barcodeValue" value="1234"><br>    <br>
    </div>

    <div id="submit">
        <input type="button" onclick="generateBarcode();"     value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Generate &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">         <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print')" value="Print" />
    </div>
</form>

<?php
$barcodeValue = $_POST["barcodeValue"];
$save = file_get_contents("save.txt");
$save = "$barcodeValue" . $save;
file_put_contents("save.txt", $save);
echo $save;
?>
```

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibKEF.png)

How to save the input data in save.txt file. When i clicked generate button the text file not showing in same folder.

Comment: Do you have an existing file or you will create a new text file?

Comment: @monace19 yes i create save.txt in same folder but the input data not save in save.txt

Comment: I deleted the save.txt in same folder but if i click generate the save.txt not create in same folder

Comment: Can you get the contents of save.txt?

Comment: You don't have any script that will create a new txt file

Comment: @monace19 this code can create save.txt in same folder sir, I see this code to Dutchie432 :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you have no submit button so your form was not actually posting when you pressed the button. if you look at my edits you can see I changed the button from input type="button" to type="submit". That allows for the form to submit back to the same php script.

Your script also was causing errors because you accessed `$_POST["barcodeValue"]` without checking if it existed. You also have to check if the save.txt exists before reading from it. If analyze my edits you can see how checking if the variables are available will help quite a bit.

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
    <div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
    <h1>BARCODE GENERATOR</h1>
    <div id="generator"> Please fill in the code :
        <input  type="text" name="barcodeValue" id="barcodeValue" value="1234"><br>    <br>
    </div>

    <div id="submit">
        <input type="submit"   value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Generate &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;">
    </div>
</form>

<?php


    if(isset($_POST["barcodeValue"]))
    {
        $barcodeValue = $_POST["barcodeValue"];
        if(file_exists("save.txt"))
            $save = file_get_contents("save.txt");
        else
            $save = "";
        $save = $barcodeValue . $save;
        file_put_contents("save.txt", $save);
        echo $save;
    }


?>
```

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: hi Jason i need the onclick="generateBarcode(); to generate barcode in same page but when i change to input type="submit" the genete button cant create barcode

Comment: `<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >` change your form variable like this

Comment: So you want the the button to generate this without reloading the page if I am understanding you correct?